# What is the entry address for a program loaded with SAM-BA?

Tags: embedded, arm, atmel

In the past few days I've found out that SAM-BA can not only write/read flash/ram, but it can also be used as a bootloader. My question is, how does one know where to put the program so that SAM-BA can run it after initial boot sequence? I couldn't find that information in ANY of pdfs provided as a documentation.

I've found a blog post by Adam Pierce and got a linker script that links the program against RAM. Now the RAM memory is at 0x00200000, but the entry point is linked at 0x00202000 - with an explanation that we need to leave "some" memory for SAM-BA.

Why 0x2000 bytes? How can I be sure if it's the right address, and where can I found some information to confirm this?

Comment: The start address will be device specific, what device are you using? Most devices have an associated device specific SAM-BA application note.

Comment: I am using Atmel's AT91SAM7X256. I tried looking it up in several places, but to no avail. I couldn't find any information in the uC datasheet, nor in SAM-BA User's Guide. I would appreciate any hint on where to find this info.

Comment: I have found a short note in AT91SAM CAN Bootloader User Notes:

SAM-BA Boot4CAN copies itself in the SRAM and uses a block of internal SRAM for
variables and stacks. In consequence, t
he user area starts at address 0x202_000.

So thats about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in section 21 of [the datasheet.](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc6120.pdf)

> **21.5 Hardware and Software Constraints**
>
> SAM-BA boot copies itself in the SRAM and uses a block of internal SRAM for variables and stacks.
> The remaining available size for the user code is 122880 bytes for
> SAM7x512, 57344 bytes for SAM7X256 and 24576 bytes for SAM7X128.

Table 21-4 in that document shows that the user-area start address for all three devices is 0x202000.

Comment: Thank you, I must've missed that.